# How to approach newly found father's other family?

Tags: communication

My husband who is 68 years old just found out who his father is.  He is deceased, but I have located a family member of his.  They probably don't know anything about my husband.  All I want truthfully is a photo.

I don't want to cause any problems or give information that they perhaps did not know.  How do I approach this situation?

Comment: Hi @Jaye, welcome to G&FH.SE. Please review this thread "[How to reach out to strangers that could be relatives from an illegitimate birth?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/how-to-reach-out-to-strangers-that-could-be-relatives-from-an-illegitimate-birth)")  as I believe it may address your question.  If not, could you rephrase your question to be more specific on what you are looking for?

Comment: If you do add more details, please be aware, as you seem to be, that nothing that could identify potentially living persons can be included.  We describe this and how to ask such questions carefully in our [Help/on-topic].